# JSF External Context getRealPath

Tags: jsf, weblogic

I'm using JSF 2.1.2.

On my locale machine

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("navigation.xml")
```

returns the correct path to the file!

On another machine it returns `null`.

I deployed the same WAR file on both machines.
Both are running a Weblogic Server 10.3.5

The JSF libraries are in the `WEB-INF/libs` folder, I'm not using the version shipped with weblogic.

Any idea why this does not work?

Any other proposal how I can get the path to the file, so that I don't have to call `getRealPath`?

**EDIT:** I switched to JSF 2.0.6. Because JSF 2.1 requires Java Servlet 3.0, which is not yet supported by Weblogic. But the error is still the same...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does getRealPath() return null when deployed with a .war file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file)