# Spring MVC: FileNotFoundException "\Uploads\MyUploads\loading.gif (The system cannot find the path specified)"

Tags: java, servlets

**Problem Context:**

I am trying to persist a file, uploaded by the user, to file system.

**Description:**

Actually, I am using Spring MVC (3.0) and this is how I am trying to persist the file,

```
String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
String filePath = "/Uploads/MyUploads/"+ new Date().getTime()+orgName;// Unique Image Name
File dest = new File(filePath);
file.transferTo(dest);
```

I have a folder `Uploads\MarketplaceUploads`, at the root of my application. But still I am getting `FileNotFoundException "\Uploads\MyUploads\loading.gif` (The system cannot find the path specified)".

**Below is the directory structure:**

[image]

Comment: the answer may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/34162565/3627736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you add the web-app context path before using the file

```
String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/Uploads/MyUploads/"+ new Date().getTime()+orgName;// Unique Image Name
File dest = new File(filePath);
file.transferTo(dest);
```

From the javadoc of `getRealPath()`

> Gets the real path corresponding to the given virtual path.
>   For example, if path is equal to /index.html, this method will return the absolute file path on the server's filesystem to which a request of the form http://://index.html would be mapped, where  corresponds to the context path of this ServletContext.
>   The real path returned will be in a form appropriate to the computer and operating system on which the servlet container is running, including the proper path separators.
>   Resources inside the /META-INF/resources directories of JAR files bundled in the application's /WEB-INF/lib directory must be considered only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR file, in which case the path to the unpacked location must be returned.
>   This method returns null if the servlet container is unable to translate the given virtual path to a real path.

Comment: Thanks it work's. But still the file is saving in build directory. Is there is any way to save this image inside root application. Because every time I build the project all the uploaded file cleaned. So I need to save this image inside root or inside web folder(with CSS and Js folder). PLease help

Comment: @user960567, when your application is deployed in production your root wont be available (i.e.) your development version, you will need to use a database to store your information, alternatively, the files wont disappear in production because you wont be redeploying.

Answer (score 4):

You should not store uploaded files in public web content.

- It will not work in any way when the WAR is not expanded by the container (this is configureable at server level and not controllable whenever it's a 3rd party host). You simply can't write the uploaded file to it in any way.
- All uploads will get lost whenever you redeploy (an update) of the WAR. You need to remember to backup them everytime.
- In some servers, all uploads will also get lost whenver the server is restarted. You have no control over this whenever it's a 3rd party host.

Store them outside the server's webapps folder. Provide the root of this location as an absolute disk file system path to your webapp, e.g. by a properties file or a VM argument. An alternative is to store them in a database, this is often the only solution if it's a 3rd party host which doesn't offer access to a fixed location outside the web content.

Comment: Is you mean that I should give absolute path, e.g, C:\webapps\.... But I think this is a bad idea because I do not know the absolute location until the application is deployed in the original server.

Comment: That's exactly why you need to make it configureable by e.g. a properties file or VM argument, as stated in the answer. If you find this a bad idea, fine, but don't complain at me once you lose all the uploaded files at some point.

Comment: Thanks. However I don't see these type of problems in ASP.NET Frameworks., like, ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @user960567: ASP.NET or anything else, the suggestion still holds.

Comment: @adeel-ansari: What do you mean?. BTW, I agree with balus that I should use a configuration key to store the root absolute path or use database instead.

Comment: @adeel-ansari, this is really pain full for OP that you guys are down voting the question. Is the question does not make any sense?

Comment: @user960567: Revoked the negative and reinstated the positive vote, after improving your question. You can fix it, if you find anything wrong with what I have written. BTW, I meant the directory having users uploads should not be the part of web application whatsoever. No matter if it is ASP.NET or Python.

Comment: @adeel-ansari why? There is always a security risk to saving the file outside the application. This is the one of reason why third party host don't allow this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead,

```
String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
// the leading slash is important
String filePath = "/Uploads/MyUploads/"+ new Date().getTime()+orgName; 
File dest = new File(req.getServletContext().getResource(filePath).toURI());
file.transferTo(dest);
```

Using `getRealPath()` is, indeed, a bad idea. Simply, because you are trying to read a resource which actually resides inside the application. Therefore, we need not use getRealPath(). Furthermore, if the application is being run from a bundled `.war` file, `getRealPath()` will return `null`.

**Resources:**

- Similar problem is being discussed over here, [Why does getRealPath() return null when deployed with a .war file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file)

Comment: This is not working. I am getting the same error. I am looking actually the same which we use in ASP.NET environment, like Server.MapPath or string started with ~ sign

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, can you please explain why it is a bad idea?

Comment: @epoch: Simply because you are trying to read a resource which actually resides inside the application. We need not use `getRealPath()`. Further, if the application is being run from a bundled `.war` file, `getRealPath()` will return `null`.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari, that does not make it a bad idea, i use this in production systems, and it ensures the virtual path is correctly mapped to your application root.Further, that is not true, the web container still has a servlet context, the only reason it will return null is if the context does not exist or the translation cannot be performed

Comment: @epoch: Hope this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file, will make things clear. Can't help much.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari, Thanks adeel, the reason why it works for us is because our .war file is always expanded. I understand now that it will not work if the .war file is not expanded.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari, then what should I use. Your method is not working.

Comment: @user960567: Try to keep your `Uploads` directory at the same level as your `WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: It is in the same level. See above image,

Comment: new Date().getTime() is just used for making the file name unique. I know there may be many other ways(like GUID,etc). With getRealPath everything is working just fine.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari: serveletContext.getResource(filePath) is null. FYI, the file is not exist yet. I am uploading a file and saving it in disk.