# ATG - How to access deployed files from a GenericService based service?

Tags: atg

I have a service (subclass of GenericService) that needs to find the path to the **deploy** directory [under the application server's install directory] at run-time without hard-coding it; that path varies between the many environments in which we work on a daily basis.

I found how do this from within a JSP file, the following gives exactly what I need, but I cannot find a ServeLetContext:

```
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
String path = context.getRealPath("/my/path");
```

However, I don't have the **request** or **session** objects in the service, or do I?  I've been looking at

```
getAdminServlet().getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/my/path");
```

but I'm not getting a context back.

We are using ATG 9.1 on JBoss 4.2.

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Any service that implements `GenericService` will also have access to `getNucleus()` which in turn gives you access to `getRealPath(String str)`.

As I'm not sure why you need to use `context.getRealPath(String str)` you should note that there are occasions where it may not be best suited for your needs. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file) you won't be able to access it if you deploy your application in a .war.

That said, this may be a simpler approach that doesn't care which environment you deploy it to:

```
private String getBasePath() {
    String basePath = DynamoEnv.getProperty("atg.dynamo.server.home");
    return basePath;
}
```

It is environment agnostic and since you can't run ATG without a home folder... should work wonders.

Comment: radimpe - Thanks for the response.  I used getNucleus().getRealPath("xxx"), and the result was (on Windows): "C:\ATG\ATG9.1\home\doc\xxx" and atg.dynamo.server.home returns (on Windows) "C:\ATG\ATG9.1\home".  Neither of which will get me to the "deploy" directory, which is under the application server.

Comment: What are you running you ATG instance on? Do you perhaps have a dynamo.env file that incorrectly specify the atg.dynamo.server.home value? Does this property show up in your dynamo.log during startup? I am running WebSphere and double checked that I don't specify it anywhere and it resolves correctly.