# Upload photos to OpenShift. Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, openshift

I have deployed **.war** file of my Spring MVC app at OpenShift server.
There every user can change there photos. It works at my localhost, but i need to upload photo at OpenShift server and to put a path of every photo to database.
This is my method for uploading files

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/updateinfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAvatar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return "redirect:/user";
    }

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            String relativeWebPath = "/resources/avatars/";
            String absoluteFilePath = context.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
            String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
            // String name=file.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println(absoluteFilePath);
            String path = absoluteFilePath + "/" + name;
            File convFile = new File(absoluteFilePath + "/" + name);
            this.usersService.addUserAvatar(principal.getName(), "/var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/app-root/data/"+name);
            System.out.println(convFile.getAbsolutePath());
            file.transferTo(convFile);
            System.out.println("You have uploaded file");
            return "redirect:/user";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to upload");
            return "redirect:/user";
        }
    }
    return " redirect:/user";
}
```

But this path doesn't work. Log file shows me this exception

```
    /var/lib/openshift/56ae274f0c1e664bf3000158/jbossews/null/vr833vqI_wc.jpg
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/vr833vqI_wc.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

Help pls!

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file). Also, for image (or other persistent data storage), the data directory is to be used, which is best accessed using [the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#__code_data_code).

Comment: @JiriFiala, thanx for an answer, but i solved this problem with this path: **/var/lib/openshift/PROJECT_ID/app-root/data/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem adding `<Context docBase="/var/lib/openshift/PROJECT_ID/app-root/data" path="/data" />`
to the **.openshift/config/server.xml** into `<HOST>` tag.
After that i could get my photos throught `https://appname-domain.rhcloud.com/data/photo.jpg`

Comment: Spot on, works perfectly. Created a folder under app-root/data and added this to server.xml: <Context docBase="/var/lib/openshift/PROJECT_ID/app-root/data/documents" path="/documents" />      Now I can serve documents like this: https://www.mydomain.co.uk/documents/invoices/S049952.pdf