# ServletContext.getRealPath(filename) behaving differently on local vs. dev environments

Tags: java, weblogic, csrf

We are running a Java 5 EE web app on Weblogic 10.3.6 and are having issues with the dev environment that doesn't show up in our local, near-identical environment.

The issue is that we are trying to incorporate a 3rd party library called CSRFGuard, and it works fine locally but fails to deploy on the dev server.  I put in some debugging code and the line where it fails is this:

```
String fileName = context.getRealPath(resourceName);
```

resourceName in this case is the string 'WEB-INF/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties' which corresponds with a file named Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties located in the WEB-INF folder.

Locally, the call returns "C:\deployment\myapp.ear\mywebapp.war\WEB-INF\Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties" but on the dev server it returns null.  I unpacked the EAR file on the dev server, and sure enough, the file is there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you deploying an exploded WAR?

Comment: have u checked this link , it looks similar to your problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file)

Comment: Yes, I actually found that right after I posted this.  It did indeed fix the issue.  I changed the weblogic config to check the "Archived Real Path Enabled" checkbox.