# How can a web application enumerate the folder structure inside its WebContent

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to get the directory structure inside WebContent folder without resorting to any config file. Is there a way to list folders and pages within the application?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/3511123

Comment: So I get real path, then enumerate the files from there right?

Comment: Exactly, as soon as you have the real path, you can use standard Java filesystem API(s). **Warning**: some servlet containers allow to deploy  webapps without expanding the WAR file, i.e. without unpacking it - in such case, `getRealPath()` returns `null`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/536260/3511123

Comment: Thanks @JozefChocholacek. That's very useful.