# request.getServletContext().getRealPath() is returning null in jsp servlet

Tags: servlets

This is the statement:

```
System.out.println("getServletContext : " + request.getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator));
```

Output:

```
getServletContext : null
```

This is the statement:

```
System.out.println(request.getServletContext());
```

Output:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@1cb0b163
```

I need the actual file path, because I need to upload my files inside the application directory.

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536228/why-does-getrealpath-return-null-when-deployed-with-a-war-file)? Don't use getRealPath method.

Comment: Do you save your Word or Excel documents into the installation directory of Office? No. For good reasons: these are data, that don't belong there. And you really don't want all these documents to dsappear if you reinstall Office. Same here: uploaded data do NOT belong to the application directory. Not to mention that you could even not have any directory at all if you deploy a war file.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But then where to upload my files? Please give me some more idea about it.

Comment: And sorry. I said application directory. My mistake. I meant my project directory. The directory which will be created from my war file. Is that folder alright? Or should I save my files in a folder outside my project directory? @JBNizet

Comment: If it's created from your war file, it will be deleted and recreated when you redeploy the app, every time you fix some bug and make a new release. Changing the name of that folder from "application directory" to "project directory" doesn't change anything. You should save your files **outside** of this directory.

Comment: @SMA It worked with "/". Previously I was using File.separator. And I tested it on my web server as well after deploying my war file. Files are getting uploaded.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info @JBNizet